# Installation of rdyncall package for R

Tags: r, installation

Hi I have a problem with installation rdyncall. rdyncall is in archive and I tried this:

```
url = "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rdyncall/rdyncall_0.7.5.tar.gz"

pkgFile = "rdyncall_0.7.5.tar.gz"

download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)

install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source",repos=NULL)

unlink(pkgFile)
```

after install.packages("...") I got this error:

```
ERROR: failed to lock directory 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.1' for modifying
Try removing 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/00LOCK-rdyncall'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-3.1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\user\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "rdyncall_0.7.5.tar.gz"' had status 3
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rdyncall_0.7.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have removed permission in windows "only to read" but nothing. I tried it at 3.1.2, 3.0, and 2.15 version of R.

Comment: Updated answer below using the latest version of rdyncall. The currently accepted answer is long outdated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try it at Win8 and it is working. At win 8.1 and win7 it is not working. I dont known why, but if I after that copy "R Folder" from program files (from Win8) to Win 8.1. It is working.

Answer (score -1):

The `rdyncall` package has recently been updated on github & will now work on the latest version of Windows, Mac or Ubuntu. To install it just do

```
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("hongyuanjia/rdyncall")
library(rdyncall)
```

The SDL, SDL_image and SDL_mixer DLLs (version 1.2) (on Windows) have to be installed first from https://libsdl.org/release/, https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/ and https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/) (the 64 bit DLLs are to be put underR-4.2.1/bin/x64`) or using

```
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jean-Romain/lidRviewer/master/sdl.R")
```

On Ubuntu they can be installed using

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2
```

An example to use `rdyncall` for the fast display of raster images using SDL & OpenGL is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using).