# Most efficient way of drawing a heatmap from matrix with OpenGL?

Tags: r, opengl

Assume a matrix `m` of integer values:

```
m <- matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
```

Given a colour palette that maps those values from 1 to 10 to some colours, how to show matrix `m` as a heatmap in R with OpenGL graphics, e.g. using the `rgl` package? (Preferably in the most efficient way.)

Comment: I think that calling SDL and OpenGL directly using rdyncall could be most efficient to do this, but haven't figured out myself exactly how to do this - looking for an answer to this question myself too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using-rdynca. Out of the standard R functions provided to display an image raster, grid.raster in library(grid) is the fastest that I know of...

Comment: I've learned recently that `nativeRaster` can be really fast. The `{nara}` package uses it: https://github.com/coolbutuseless/nara.

Comment: Ha thanks - hadn't seen that one! With that one I can get a real-time smooth Mandelbrot zoomer - cool!

Comment: Did you also find an efficient way to do the colour mapping? If so, you might want to post an answer below to your original question! I am sure many others would find it useful!

Answer (score 1):

The very thorough answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using-qtpain) suggests this may not be what you want; you might want to try the solution below against the other solutions benchmarked there.  Nonetheless:

Set up data and colour map

```
set.seed(101)
library(viridisLite)
vv <- viridis(10)
m <- matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
```

Draw the picture:

```
library(rgl)
view3d(theta=0, phi=0)  ## head-on view
par3d(zoom=0.7)         ## (almost) fill window
surface3d(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, z = matrix(0, 10,10), 
          color = vv[m],
          smooth=FALSE, lit=FALSE  ## turn off smoothing/lights
 )
```

You may need to use `pop3d()` between surfaces to clear the previous surface ...

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is very slow compared to just using grid.raster. Looking at the demo of rdyncall, which allows you to call OpenGL & SDL directly, there should be faster ways still though using OpenGL acceleration, https://dyncall.org/demos/soulsalicious/index.html, but haven't figured that out yet. That demo https://dyncall.org/demos/soulsalicious/soulsalicious.tar.gz shows how to display PNG images etc, so shouldn't be too far for what we would need...

Comment: But still no answer to my 4 year old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using-rdynca. Maybe I should ask ChatGPT for some help?

Comment: Sorry, this is just what I know how to do. Someone has a recent deleted answers under your old question, don't know why they deleted it (haven't tried it for myself) ... ?

Comment: No worries! How can I see that deleted answer? Or is it only above a certain reputation that you can see deleted answers? Curious to see the code. ChatGPT got me somewhat one the way to an answer, but still needs a bit of debugging...

Comment: Just found that nativeRaster of the {nara} package is very fast: github.com/coolbutuseless/nara. So that's currently the fastest option I know about! He even programmed Pacman with it in R! https://github.com/coolbutuseless/pacman See also my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using-rdynca

Comment: Here is a short demo I just made of that {nara} package, using it for real-time Mandelbrot zooms, cf. function zoom() in https://github.com/tomwenseleers/mandelExplorer

Comment: So I posted an SDL/OpenGL solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using/76472961?noredirect=1#comment134865427_76472961. Still some scope to do the colour mapping also in OpenGL though - right now I am doing that beforehand...