# How to efficiently animate image rasters using OpenGL acceleration in R?

Tags: r, opengl, rgl

This is a follow-up question to these ones:

- [Performant 2D OpenGL graphics in R for fast display of raster image using qtpaint (qt) or rdyncall (SDL/OpenGL) packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using-qtpain)
- [Most efficient way of drawing a heatmap from matrix with OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979001/most-efficient-way-of-drawing-a-heatmap-from-matrix-with-opengl)

I'd like to interactively see the output of spatial discrete simulations of cellular automata in 2D. So I am starting simple and trying to understand how fast I can go with drawing matrices of integer values. I am trying here with the `rgl` package, that, to my knowledge, is the package providing the (theoretically) fastest(?) graphics device in R.

I am trying this approach with `rgl` but the frame rate is 30 frames per sec which I find rather low (see code below). My example is drawing raster images from R matrices that are 100x100 only. Moreover, I am getting flickering, I don't know why.

Here's my approach (following an answer from @ben-bolker) and now using feedback from @user2554330.

```
library(viridisLite)
library(rgl)

n_colours <- 100
n_row <- 500
n_col <- 500
vv <- viridis(n_colours)

setup <- function() {
  view3d(theta=0, phi=0)  ## head-on view
  #par3d(zoom=0.65, windowRect = c(0,0, n_col, n_row), viewport = c(0,0, n_col, n_row))
  par3d(zoom=0.65, windowRect = c(0,0, n_col, n_row), viewport = c(0,0, n_col, n_row))
}

# draw <- function(m) {
#   d <- dim(m)
#   surface3d(x = 1:d[1], y = 1:d[2], z = matrix(0, d[1], d[2]), 
#             color = vv[m],
#             smooth=FALSE, lit=FALSE  ## turn off smoothing/lights
#   )
# }

# draw2 <- function(m) {
#   par3d(skipRedraw = TRUE)  # but skip blank update
#   clear3d()
#   
#   d <- dim(m)
#   surface3d(x = 1:d[1], y = 1:d[2], z = matrix(0, d[1], d[2]), 
#             color = vv[m],
#             smooth=FALSE, lit=FALSE  ## turn off smoothing/lights
#   )
#   par3d(skipRedraw = FALSE) # Make sure image is shown
# }

draw3 <- function(colours) {
  par3d(skipRedraw = TRUE)  # but skip blank update
  clear3d()

  d <- dim(m)
  surface3d(x = 1:d[1], y = 1:d[2], z = matrix(0, d[1], d[2]), 
            color = colours,
            smooth=FALSE, lit=FALSE  ## turn off smoothing/lights
  )
  par3d(skipRedraw = FALSE) # Make sure image is shown
}

nframes <- 100

n_matrices <- list()
for(i in 1:nframes) {
  n_matrices[[i]] <- vv[matrix(sample(1:n_colours, n_row*n_col, replace = TRUE), nrow = n_row)]
}

setup()
# time <- system.time({
#   for (i in 1:nframes) {
#     draw(n_matrices[[i]])
#     par3d(skipRedraw = FALSE) # Make sure image is shown
#     
#     par3d(skipRedraw = TRUE)  # but skip blank update
#     pop3d()
#   }
#   par3d(skipRedraw = FALSE)
# })

time <- system.time({
  for (i in 1:nframes) {
    draw3(n_matrices[[i]])
  }
})


fps <- nframes/time[3]
fps
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the flicker will also slow down your display.  Your `pop3d()` call is asking `rgl` to redraw the image with no surface shown.  You can get about twice the speed by telling `rgl` to skip that redraw:

```
time <- system.time({
  for (i in 1:nframes) {
    draw(n_matrices[[i]])
    par3d(skipRedraw = FALSE) # Make sure image is shown

    par3d(skipRedraw = TRUE)  # but skip blank update
    pop3d()
  }
  par3d(skipRedraw = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: Thank you @user2554330! This indeed speeds up things twofold. Do you happen to know how to make the window size such that one matrix element corresponds to one pixel exactly?

Comment: I've swapped `pop3d()` with `clear3d()` and moved the drawing/clearing functions to `draw3()`. Also, I am passing only now the colours to `draw3d()` to see if there would be any performance improvement but it seems it is marginal. Now, the last frame for some reason is always shifted and enlarged (pixels look bigger). Would you know why? Also, how to play with the zoom parameter? How to get the window completely filled up with the texture without any white space around? Would you also know why I can't kill the window till the end of the for-loop?

Comment: It seems that this approach of a for-loop makes the window not interactive with the mouse. Is it because the computation is so busy drawing new frames that it hardly has time to capture an event from thte mouse?